# Reprojecting results in invalid geometries

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geometry, geopandas

I have a GeoJSON file that contains some buffers in WGS84 EPSG: 4326 and I am trying to reproject it to WGS84/UTM zone 32N EPSG: 32632.

I am using GeoPandas to do it with the `to_crs` method, but the resulting geodataframe has invalid geometries.

I have also tried to reproject it with QGIS, which produces the same problem.

Here is one of the buffers so that you can try to reproduce it if you want:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": { 
    "type": "name",
    "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
  "features": [
    { 
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "s_id": 21405, "lon": 11.8167, "lat": 53.5833, "alt": 55, "alt_dem": 56, "gss_id": 1010300, "genus": "Acer", "species": "Acer platanoides", "phase_id": 60, "year": 2017, "day": 92, "date": "2017-04-02", "Label": "DBL" },
      "geometry": { 
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [ [ [ 690450.22425951808691, 5940850.354278050363064 ], [ 690430.963166206842288, 5940458.285716732032597 ], [ 690373.365381131065078, 5940069.992989986203611 ], [ 690277.985602446948178, 5939689.215569032356143 ], [ 690145.742389563238248, 5939319.620548590086401 ], [ 689977.909316911478527, 5938964.767330746166408 ], [ 689776.102708728285506, 5938628.07334597222507 ], [ 689542.266072969068773, 5938312.781141395680606 ], [ 689278.651384264230728, 5938021.927153304219246 ], [ 688987.797396172652952, 5937758.312464599497616 ], [ 688672.505191596457735, 5937524.475828840397298 ], [ 688335.811206822050735, 5937322.669220657087862 ], [ 687980.957988978479989, 5937154.836148004978895 ], [ 687611.362968535977416, 5937022.592935121618211 ], [ 687230.585547582595609, 5936927.213156437501311 ], [ 686842.292820836300962, 5936869.615371361374855 ], [ 686450.22425951808691, 5936850.354278050363064 ], [ 686058.155698199872859, 5936869.615371361374855 ], [ 685669.862971453578211, 5936927.213156437501311 ], [ 685289.085550500196405, 5937022.592935121618211 ], [ 684919.490530057693832, 5937154.836148004978895 ], [ 684564.637312214123085, 5937322.669220657087862 ], [ 684227.943327439716086, 5937524.475828840397298 ], [ 683912.651122863520868, 5937758.312464599497616 ], [ 683621.797134771943092, 5938021.927153304219246 ], [ 683358.182446067105047, 5938312.781141395680606 ], [ 683124.345810307888314, 5938628.07334597222507 ], [ 682922.539202124695294, 5938964.767330746166408 ], [ 682754.706129472935572, 5939319.620548590086401 ], [ 682622.462916589225642, 5939689.215569032356143 ], [ 682527.083137905108742, 5940069.992989986203611 ], [ 682469.485352829331532, 5940458.285716732032597 ], [ 682450.22425951808691, 5940850.354278050363064 ], [ 682469.485352829331532, 5941242.422839368693531 ], [ 682527.083137905108742, 5941630.715566114522517 ], [ 682622.462916589225642, 5942011.492987068369985 ], [ 682754.706129472935572, 5942381.088007510639727 ], [ 682922.539202124695294, 5942735.94122535455972 ], [ 683124.345810307888314, 5943072.635210128501058 ], [ 683358.182446067105047, 5943387.927414705045521 ], [ 683621.797134771943092, 5943678.781402796506882 ], [ 683912.651122863520868, 5943942.396091501228511 ], [ 684227.943327439716086, 5944176.232727260328829 ], [ 684564.637312214123085, 5944378.039335443638265 ], [ 684919.490530057693832, 5944545.872408095747232 ], [ 685289.085550500196405, 5944678.115620979107916 ], [ 685669.862971453578211, 5944773.495399663224816 ], [ 686058.155698199872859, 5944831.093184739351273 ], [ 686450.22425951808691, 5944850.354278050363064 ], [ 686842.292820836300962, 5944831.093184739351273 ], [ 687230.585547582595609, 5944773.495399663224816 ], [ 687611.362968535977416, 5944678.115620979107916 ], [ 687980.957988978479989, 5944545.872408095747232 ], [ 688335.811206822050735, 5944378.039335443638265 ], [ 688672.505191596457735, 5944176.232727260328829 ], [ 688987.797396172652952, 5943942.396091501228511 ], [ 689278.651384264230728, 5943678.781402796506882 ], [ 689542.266072969068773, 5943387.927414705045521 ], [ 689776.102708728285506, 5943072.635210128501058 ], [ 689977.909316911478527, 5942735.94122535455972 ], [ 690145.742389563238248, 5942381.088007510639727 ], [ 690277.985602446948178, 5942011.492987068369985 ], [ 690373.365381131065078, 5941630.715566114522517 ], [ 690430.963166206842288, 5941242.422839368693531 ], [ 690450.22425951808691, 5940850.354278050363064 ] ] 
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: GeoJSON only really supports 4326. Your coordinates are not geographic, so you're deep into unknown realms.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't look at the coordinates and thought that they were WGS84. It seems that I made a mistake while I was creating the buffers. So, in reality they are 32632, but the crs is set as WGS84. Thanks, I will go back and create them correctly.